How does Mirio Togata manage to carry the energy of Nejire Hado?
Supposedly, the power of Mirio Togata was permeation, but now he's also able to carry the energy of Nejire Hado and punch others with it.
How does Mirio Togata manage to carry the energy of Nejire Hado?

There are 3 possibilities.

Mirio has an ability we aren't familiar with (unlikely)
Nejire can control who her ability is harmful to (unlikely)
It's fiction and doesn't use "hard magic" or set rules 100% of the time. Sometimes writers are liberal with their actions and see how much they can get away with while the reader suspends their disbelief of reality in their made-up world. Push it too far and we question it. This is most likely a case of that.


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
